Sample gradients in grouped scatter plots in seaborn?
Background
In biology (and perhaps other fields) there are times that you'd like to visualize the difference between "control" and "treated" conditions. Often one would collect several samples from each condition and plot distributions, scatters, or swarm plots side by side. In this case, since samples are independent, the overall distribution change is all that one can extract.
But sometimes, by virtue of a wise experimental setup, the very same sample point can undergo both conditions. Thus, one can directly assess the effect of "treatment" one every sample, and check whether his/her hypothesis regarding the treatment is homogeneously applied to all samples or not. An insightful plot is something like this that I see quite frequently in the literature:

Problem
I wonder if there's a way to plot such plots using seaborn. Boxplot is the most similar thing that I came across to. But it lacks two features:

It only scatters outliers (instead of all samples)
Gradient lines between adjacent categories of all groups are not drawn

Is there an easy way to do these two? Any idea is highly appreciated.

Assuming such an example:
import seaborn as sns

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
                   'B': [1, 2, 4, 6, 7]})

ax = sns.boxplot(df)

Output:

You could transpose your DataFrame, reset_index and overlay a line plot:
import seaborn as sns

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
                   'B': [1, 2, 4, 6, 7]})

ax = sns.boxplot(df)

(df.T.reset_index(drop=True)
   .plot(marker='o', ls=':', color='k', legend=False, ax=ax)
)

Output:

